# Unwanted residual borders in ggplot pdf only

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

The code below produces the correct plot in a window and in a png file. However, in pdf-output when viewed with Acrobat 9 Pro under Windows 7, there are strange residual borders; these do not turn up with Sumatra viewer.

[image: Borders in pdf plot]

```
library(ggplot2)
pdf("hist.pdf")
qplot(carat,data=diamonds,geom="histogram",binwidth=0.2,fill=carat>=1)
dev.off()



R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that is a rendering artifact produced by Adobe. If you can post a link to the file I can give you more details about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a rendering problem of Adobe Pro 9.0. I tried again with Adobe Reader 11, and there is no problem with it.